# rewrite path using mod rewrite apache

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm new to rewriting and I was looking for the regex that I can use in order to create my own url rewrite rules. I was wondering how to rewrite such url

```
https://www.mydomain.com/accout/log/folder1/folder2
```

To

```
https://www.mydomain.com/folder2
```

I want to target foder2 directly hiding the real path. is there a way how to create a fake path as well??

In which .htaccess I have to include the rewrite code?

Thanks

**Update**

Thanks @ThinkingMonkey, the code was good and it works, but there was a handler missing that's why it didn't work at first.

Comment: this site may can help you to create your regex: http://txt2re.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to `conf` files, you can create an alias for `folder2`.

```
Alias /folder2 /accout/log/folder1/folder2
```

And do a

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /folder2
```

in a `.htaccess` placed in `accout/log/folder1/folder2`.
*Remember, for the above to work `mod_alias` has to be enabled as `Alias` is a directive from `mod_alias`*.

Or you can add this in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:\.\w+|/)$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/folder2)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /accout/log/folder1/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/accout/log/folder1/folder2
RewriteRule accout/log/folder1/(folder2)(/(.*))?$ $1$2 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @ThinkingMonkey, Yes, I don't have mod_alias on my server, but can include the code you provided me in .htaccess file. That was very helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried it, but didn't work. possibly either I'm missing something or there is something wrong with code. Can you check again please. Thanks

Comment: ok, there is another weird thing in here. when I do the same exact coding, the url return without www and expand the full link instead. any idea what's going on??

Comment: @Digitalsite if I understand correctly, Its the trailing slash problem wrt `expand the full link`.

Comment: @Digitalsite Check update in answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8105/discussion-between-thinkingmonkey-and-digital-site)